# Install R package error - compilation failed in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, devtools, forecast, kernlab

I try to install R packages by using devtools (for specific version) but got some errors.
I have to install packages that's specific version and use specific R version (4.1.*) plz.

#### R, devtools version

- R version : 4.1.3
- devtools: 2.4.4
  [image]

#### Install packages

- forecast : 8.13
- kernlab : 0.9-29

#### Install commands

`install_version("forecast", version = "8.13")`
`install_version("kernlab", version = "0.9-29")`

or add option `dependencies=TRUE`

#### Error list

```
cc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I
'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-ma
p=/build/r-base-NlA7dw/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-s
ecurity -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c registerDynamicSymbol.c -o registerDynami
cSymbol.o
g++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcp
p/include' -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fde
bug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-NlA7dw/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -We
rror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c updateMatrices.cpp -o update
Matrices.o
g++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcp
p/include' -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fde
bug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-NlA7dw/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -We
rror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c updateTBATSMatrices.cpp -o u
pdateTBATSMatrices.o
g++ -std=gnu++14 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o forec
ast.so calcBATS.o calcTBATS.o etsTargetFunction.o etsTargetFunctionWrapper.o etscalc.o e
tspolyroot.o makeBATSMatrices.o makeTBATSMatrices.o registerDynamicSymbol.o updateMatric
es.o updateTBATSMatrices.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -l
R
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:10: recipe for target 'forecast.so' failed
make: *** [forecast.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘forecast’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/forecast’
경고메시지(들):
i.p(...)에서:
  installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpGgApec/remotes25555374bfb7/forecast’ had non-zero ex
it status
```

#### Commands I've tried

```bash
sudo apt-get install g++ 
sudo apt install gfortran 
sudo apt install libcurl4-gnutls-dev

R version upgrade 4.1.0 -> 4.1.3
R version downgrade 4.1.3 -> 4.1.0

install.packages('forecast')
install.packages('kernlab')
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  We supply a package with the most common dependencies so consider doing `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev`.  After that you can compile.

Longer answer:  Ubuntu contains a number of pre-built CRAN packages. Consider doing `sudo apt install r-cran-kernlab r-cran-forecast`.  For an older Ubuntu release this may reflect older versions.

Best answer (if you are on Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04): Consider [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/) which has all (!!) of the CRAN packages as `r-cran-binaries`, and uses `bspm` so that you can just say `install.packages(c("kernlab", "forecast"))` and *still* get everything pre-made as binaries, with dependencies, and managed via `apt`.  But we do not support 18.04 for that.

Comment: thanks to your answer, `sudo apt-get install libgdal` can help install !

Comment: That comment makes no sense as you ask above about `forecast` and `kernlab`, neither one has anything to do with `libgdal`.  Anyway... if you're helped, good.

Answer (score 1):

In general when libraries are missing, "cannot find -lXXX", you should `apt-cache search libXXX` + `-dev`, and `apt-get install` what you find.

So in this case:

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev
```

[A related answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623578/installing-blas-and-lapack-packages).

Comment: thanks to your answer, `sudo apt-get install libgdal` can help install !